# Ethernet card works during install, but not after installation

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Server 10.04.2 i686 on a very old Dell Latitude. The network card I have to use for it is a "Xircom RealPort Ethernet 10/100+Modem 56" PCMIA card.

During install, the card works fine and the installer can fetch packages from the internet. Of note is that I have to remove and reinsert the card for it to be detected properly.

When I install Ubuntu to the HD, the card stops working entirely. The kernel module `xe` which I think was allowing it to work in the installer is not loaded or even installed to the kernel on the HD. `ifconfig` shows only the loopback.

How can I get this card to work when Ubuntu is installed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be `udev` that messed up things when you reinserted the card. Run `ifconfig -a` to show all interfaces. Take a look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` end see if it mentions any of the interfaces.

If something looks strange, edit it. E.g. if it has configuration for eth0, but `ifconfig -a` lists `eth1`, you could try duplicating the existing rule, rename the interface to `eth1`, then reboot.